re-use regular expression on clientside for onkeyup event
For my xpages/jsf application I have setup for an xe:input control the following validation:
<xp:this.validators>
    <xp:validateConstraint
        regex="${application.regex_email}"
        message="please follow the rules">
    </xp:validateConstraint>
    <xp:validateRequired
        message="follow the rules">
    </xp:validateRequired>
</xp:this.validators>

The regular expression I use:
regex_email=^([\\w-]+(?:\\.[\\w-]+)*)@(acme\\.org|acme\\.com)

(so I allow only email addresses from acme.org and asme.com domains).
This works fine but I want to apply the same to validation to the client-side, so in the onkeyup event that same (or similar) regex is used. But I do not know how. Can anyone explain how to?
Basically I want to prevent that users enter capitals in the allowed mail domains.

This is pretty easy to do in HTML 5. The user can enter an invalid email address, but the form will not submit until it matches the pattern regex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

And using pattern is still better than trying to catch key events, as users can still copy paste in invalid email address into the field.

Here is a very basic javascript implementation of such validation (triggered when the input looses focus but you can use the event of your choosing)


// Note the 'i' flag to ignore case
const emailPattern = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@(acme\.org|acme\.com)/i;

const emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
const errorSpan = document.getElementById('error');
const inputForm = document.getElementById('form');

function isEmailValid() {
  const inputContent = emailInput.value;
  return emailPattern.test(inputContent);
}

function normalizeEmailInput() {
  const value = (emailInput.value ?? '').trim();
  const match = emailPattern.exec(value);
  // lower case domain only, but you could lower case the whole string and ignore what I did with the pattern
  emailInput.value = match !== null ? `${match[1]}@${match[2].toLowerCase()}` : value;
}

emailInput.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  normalizeEmailInput();
  errorSpan.style.display = isEmailValid() ? 'none' : 'inline';
});

emailInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  normalizeEmailInput();
});

inputForm.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  if (isEmailValid()) {
    alert('all good');
  } else {
    alert('Invalid email');
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
});
#error {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
<form id="form">
<input id="email" type="text" /><br />
<span id="error">Invalid email</span><br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>




Hi & tnx! It does validate but I realize now that I wrote my question in the wrong way. I basically want to force the user to enter the allowed domains in lowercase while writing.

see my updated answer

As per my comment about using the pattern attribute, here is an example. The pattern in this snippet is "foo\d" It won't let you submit until the regex matches


<form>
<input pattern="foo\d" />
<input type="submit">
</form>



